# php artisan gives failed to open stream

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am getting this error:
   PHP Warning:  require(/home/rabin/blog/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/rabin/blog/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/rabin/blog/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/rabin/blog/artisan on line 18

The commands php, composer and laravel is working fine but php artisan is always giving me this erros. Please help me out on this(screenshot included below) [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tTiL.png)

Comment: Does the file actually exist though?

Comment: I am not getting you.... You mean the project file @apokryfos if yes yeah I blog is the project folder I have navigated...

Comment: I mean  the file `/home/rabin/blog/vendor/autoload.php`. does it exist?

Comment: The vendor folder doesn't exist inside blog but the artisan file exists...

Comment: Have you done tried composer install? I'm thinking that you have this skipped that's why it's looking for a file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure you have a `composer.json` in your project root directory. If it exists then make sure you have composer installed
Then run the following command

```sh
composer update
```

It will create a vendor folder and all dependency inside the vendor folder and create the `autoload.php` file.

If you already have the vendor folder with all the dependencies inside your project then you need to regenerate the `autoload.php` file to do it run the following command

```sh
composer dump-autoload
```

NOTE: make sure `packagist.org` is NOT blocked from your network. If it is blocked then use a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the following command in your project directory to generate your vendors folder:

```
composer update
```

Comment: This is giving me another error: The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Network is unreachable
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

Comment: @RabinDhamala make sure packagist is not blocked from your network. In that case you need to use a proxy